# Can I create a symbolic link automatically after git clone

Tags: git, github

I want all my users to use my pre-commit hook. So I have created a hook directory in my main project and symlinked it to .git/hooks. So is there any way to create a symbolic link automatically after git clone So that all my users will have to follow the same standards before committing.

Comment: Sure: run `git clone ... && ln -s ...`. That will automatically make the symbolic link when the clone finishes successfully. Tell your users to use that procedure. If you meant: "can I have *Git* make the symbolic link", the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This is intentional. The creators of git wanted to make sure that code could never be run just by cloning a repository. Otherwise, git hooks would be a great way to deliver malware.

If your users choose to trust your pre-commit hooks, they have to manually enable them. If you want, you can use server-side hooks to reject changes that don't meet your standards.